# How to export a crystal report to a specific location in project itself (In WebForms)

Tags: webforms, crystal-reports

How to export a crystal report to a specific location (lets say in "download" folder) in project itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got somthing let you know if it works.  crystalReport.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,Server.MapPath("../"));